# how to restore files deleted in the Mapping virtual drive

Tags: file-recovery, recycle-bin, virtual-drive

I used psubst drive1: drive2:path /P to create the persistent virtual drive, I found that's greate, but when I delete files in those drives, they didn't appeared in the Recycle Bin, so How can I restore them?

ex: I used (p)subst K: C:/1 to create the K: driver, then I delete files in the K:, I think it will be better if they are moved to the C:/Recycle Bin but not delete persistently.

you can find more detail about psubst here: http://code.google.com/p/psubst/

Answer (score 2):

> How can I restore them?

Go to your latest backup and copy them back into their original location.

> I think it will be better if they are moved to the C:/Recycle Bin but not delete persistently.

Windows doesn't know whether your mapped virtual drive supports a recycle bin or not. Moreso, why should it put the files into YOUR Recycle Bin on C: drive (that's an awfully arbitrary decision), what if your virtual drive is mapped over a 128kbit VPN and the files are 10 gig each? Instead, it deletes them.

If you need them back, run data recovery tools on the host PC. I would recommend:

1. GetDataBack NTFS ($$)
2. R-STUDIO Network Edition ($$)
3. Recuva (Free)